# Shorten the Jquery Code for Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function animateGallery() {
  $('#image1').css({'left':'0','display' : 'block'}).animate({'left': '-150px'}, 8500,function(){
  $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
   $('#image2').css({'right':'0','display' : 'block'}).animate({'right':'-150px'},8500, function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
     $('#image3').css({'left':'0','display' : 'block'}).animate({'left':'-150px'},8500, function() {
     $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
      $('#image4').css({'right':'0','display' : 'block'}).animate({'right':'-150px'},8500, function() {
       $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
       $('#image5').css({'left':'0','display' : 'block'}).animate({'left':'-150px'},8500, function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
         $('#image6').css({'right':'0','display' : 'block'}).animate({'right':'-150px'},8500, function() {
         $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
           $('#image7').css({'left':'0','display' : 'block'}).animate({'left':'-150px'},8500, function() {
           $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
            animateGallery();
           });
          });
         });
         });
        });
       });
       });
      });
     });
     });
    });
   });
  })
  });
 }
 animateGallery();
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img id="image1" src="imge.jpg"/>
    <img id="image2" src="imge.jpg"/>
    <img id="image3" src="imge.jpg"/>
    <img id="image4" src="imge.jpg"/>
    <img id="image5" src="imge.jpg"/>
    <img id="image6" src="imge.jpg"/>
    <img id="image7" src="imge.jpg"/>
</div>
```

http://www.imperialpalace-cebu.com 
I want to imitate that gallery using the JQUERY. In the homepage.

I want to display a gallery where the images/pictures will display from left to right and right to left alternately and infinite. This code is already working but I want it to be shorten.

Comment: that's why i hate it.. so much stairs. >.<

Answer (score 0):

I think is better if you use Lightbox. http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: I don't find the functionality I want with lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

When you have repeating hierarchical code like this, you can greatly shorten it by storing the items in an array or list.  In your case, you could do:

```
var imageIDArray = new Array('image1', 'image2', etc...)
```

You can then use that array to know which one is next in line.

Comment: but image1 and image2 has different position. I already try this one but i have a hard time in getting the odd or even part in javascript. im just an newbie :(

Comment: It's basic javascript.  check `if (n%2)`, where n is the index.  if thats true n is odd

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your images in an array, then:

```
var currentIndex = 0;
var imageArr = ...;// create image array
setInterval(function(){Animate_Action();}, 8500);
function Animate_Action()
{
    var imageToAnimate = imageArr[currentIndex];

    imageToAnimate.animate(...);// your animation here.

    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    if(currentIndex >= imageArr.length) currentIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: No reason to have a currentIndex var.  you can just look up the index in the array using $this.id

Comment: but how will i get the odd or even?? like image1 start in left position.. and image2 is starts on right position..or odd is in left.. and even is in right..

Comment: var isOdd = (currentIndex % 2) == 1;

Answer (score 0):

```
var $images = $('#gallery img');
var current_image = 0;
var duration = 8000;

function animateGallery() {

  $images[current_image].css({
    'left': '0',
    'display': 'block'
  }).animate({
      'left': '-150px'
  }, duration, function(){
      $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() {

          current_image += 1;

          if (current_image > $images.length - 1) {
             current_image = 0;
          }

          animateGallery();

      });    
  });
}


 animateGallery();
```